# How to delete this file into

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am trying to delete this file but I can not correct fixing this error. The project has made a mistake when I am building or running. Someone can help me to fix it.

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: add this in project level gradle file task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: thank you so much sir issue has been resolved.

Comment: @EliasFazel Seems like issue has been resolved by your solution . Add your solution as answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in project level gradle file

```
task clean(type: Delete) { delete rootProject.buildDir }
```